# Copy Paste multiple rows from CSV to input fields in an HTML Form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to copy paste data from a CSV file to an HTML form using Jquery. My form has an array of input fields so I can do multiple inserts at the same time on submit

Now, suppose I copy paste multiple rows from a CSV file to the second column of the first row in the form, the first row of the form shows data correctly but in the second row, the data pasted starts from the first column itself, wherein it should start from the second row as it did on the first row of the form

CSV rows and cells

```
1   4   a
2   5   b
3   6   c
```

Screenshot

[image]

```
            function csv_paste_datagrid(event){
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('input').bind('paste', null, function (e) {
                        $this = $(this);
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            var columns = $this.val().split(/\s+/);
                            var i;
                            var input = $this;
                            for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                                input.val(columns[i]);
                                if( i % 3 !== 2){
                                    input = input.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().next().find('input');
                                    } else{
                                    input = input.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().next().find('input').first();
                                }
                            }
                        }, 0);
                    });
                });
```

HTML

```
            <form style="width : 100%;" id="system_validations" name="system_validations" accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST" class="form-control" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               <table style="display : inline;width : 100%;"></table>
               <table id="" class="system_form_tables_parent">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <td>
                           <table id="form_table[0]" class="system_form_tables_child" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
                              <tbody>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td style=" " id="container_validation_options[0]">
                                       <table>
                                          <tbody>
                                             <tr id="tr_validation_options[0]" style="">
                                                <th class="th_class1"><span class=""> validation_options  </span></th>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td class="td_class">   <input type="text" id="validation_options[0]" name="validation_options[0]" placeholder="" class="" value=""> </td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td class="val_error"></td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                       </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style=" " id="container_validation_display[0]">
                                       <table>
                                          <tbody>
                                             <tr id="tr_validation_display[0]" style="">
                                                <th class="th_class1"><span class=""> validation_display  </span></th>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td class="td_class">   <input type="text" id="validation_display[0]" name="validation_display[0]" placeholder="" class="" value=""> </td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td class="val_error"></td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                       </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style=" " id="container_blocked_modules[0]">
                                       <table>
                                          <tbody>
                                             <tr id="tr_blocked_modules[0]" style="">
                                                <th class="th_class1"><span class=""> blocked_modules  </span></th>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td class="td_class">   <input type="text" id="blocked_modules[0]" name="blocked_modules[0]" placeholder="" class="" value=""> </td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td class="val_error"></td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                       </table>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td style=" " id="container_validation_options[0]">
                                       <table>
                                          <tbody>
                                             <tr id="tr_validation_options[1]" style="">
                                                <th class="th_class1"><span class=""> validation_options  </span></th>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td class="td_class">   <input type="text" id="validation_options[1]" name="validation_options[1]" placeholder="" class="" value=""> </td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td class="val_error"></td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                       </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style=" " id="container_validation_display[0]">
                                       <table>
                                          <tbody>
                                             <tr id="tr_validation_display[1]" style="">
                                                <th class="th_class1"><span class=""> validation_display  </span></th>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td class="td_class">   <input type="text" id="validation_display[1]" name="validation_display[1]" placeholder="" class="" value=""> </td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td class="val_error"></td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                       </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style=" " id="container_blocked_modules[0]">
                                       <table>
                                          <tbody>
                                             <tr id="tr_blocked_modules[1]" style="">
                                                <th class="th_class1"><span class=""> blocked_modules  </span></th>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td class="td_class">   <input type="text" id="blocked_modules[1]" name="blocked_modules[1]" placeholder="" class="" value=""> </td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td class="val_error"></td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                       </table>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr style="">
                                    <td style="text-align : left;padding-left:0.5em">
                                       <table id="submit_table">
                                          <tbody>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td><input type="button" class="common_button" id="system_validations_back" name="system_validations_back" style="" value="Back" onclick="" title="Back">
                                                   <input type="reset" class="common_button" id="system_validations_reset" name="system_validations_reset" style="" value="Reset" title="Reset">
                                                   <input type="button" class="common_button" id="submit" name="system_validations_submit" onclick="" style="" value="Submit" title="Submit">
                                                </td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                       </table>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                              </tbody>
                           </table>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </form>
```

Comment: Could you share the table HTML too?

Comment: $cars10m , Hi .. i have added the form HTML, its a little lengthy though ..thanks for looking into this, appreciate it :)

Comment: @cars10m , Hi .. i have added the form HTML, its a little lengthy though ..thanks for looking into this, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, I had to clear a few double `id`s from your HTML first and also added a  class attribute (`contTD`) to your "main" container `<td>`s. After that the whole thing fell into place fairly easily:

- to prevent the actual TSV text from being pasted directly into the first input field I used `e.preventDefault()`
- I then used `.split()` twice on the TSV string to turn it into the 2D array `vals`
- I identified the `.closest()` td.contTD element (--> `td`) and its column and row numbers (`col` and `row`) by finding the `.index()` of `td` and its parent row.
- starting form the `.closest('tbody')`I then worked my way down again through the `.slice()`of rows starting with `row` and its (sliced) child input elements starting at column `col`.
- in an `.each()` loop I then assigned the value of the `vals`-array to the input element, but only if `val[i][j]` exists!

There could be further improvements to the script, as it will run trhough all `<tr>`s of the table from row `row` to the end. But I hope this is a starting point for you and has given you a few more ideas on how to work with jquery.

In my script I used a delegated paste-event-binding to the `<form>` element. This should work well with a dynamic table. I did not pack it into an extra function. But, of course, when you use it in your site it should be placed in your onload section.

And lastly: in my second `.split()` I am looking for a tab character as column separator, so this example will work with a TSV file format. If you want to apply it on space or comma separated values you should adapt the regular expression there to something like `/\s/` or `/,/` .

```js
$('form').on('paste', 'input', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // do not paste the contents into the first cell ...
  // convert TSV from clipboard into a 2D array:
  let vals=event.clipboardData.getData('text').trim().split(/\r?\n */).map(r=>r.split(/\t/));
  let td=$(this).closest('.contTD'); // closest  container TD and work from there
  let col=td.index(), row=td.parent().index(), tbdy=td.closest('tbody');
  // modify input fields of rows >= row and columns >= col: 
  tbdy.children('tr').slice(row).each((i,tr)=>{
    $(tr).find('td input:text').slice(col).each((j,ti)=>{
     if(vals[i]&&vals[i][j]!=null) ti.value=vals[i][j] } 
  )});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form style="width : 100%;" id="system_validations" name="system_validations" accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST" class="form-control" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>sample data for copying and pasting via clipboard:</label>
  <table>
   <tr><td>1</td><td>4</td><td>a</td></tr>
   <tr><td>2</td><td>5</td><td>b</td></tr>
   <tr><td>3</td><td>6</td><td>c</td></tr>
  </table>
  <table id="" class="system_form_tables_parent">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <td>
            <table id="form_table[0]" class="system_form_tables_child" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="contTD"><table>
                      <tbody><tr><th class="th_class1"><span class="">extra column</span></th></tr>
                      <tr><td class="td_class"><input type="text" value="00A"> </td></tr>
                      <tr><th></th></tr>
                      <tr><th></th></tr>
                      <tr><td class="val_error"></td></tr></tbody>
                    </table></td>
                    <td class="contTD" id="container_validation_options[0]">
                        <table>
                          <tbody>
                              <tr id="tr_validation_options[0]">
                                <th class="th_class1"><span class=""> validation_options  </span></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="td_class">   <input type="text" id="validation_options[0]" name="validation_options[0]" placeholder="" class="" value="01"> </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <th></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <th></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="val_error"></td>
                              </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td class="contTD" id="container_validation_display[0]">
                        <table>
                          <tbody>
                              <tr id="tr_validation_display[0]">
                                <th class="th_class1"><span class=""> validation_display  </span></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="td_class">   <input type="text" id="validation_display[0]" name="validation_display[0]" placeholder="" class="" value="02"> </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <th></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <th></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="val_error"></td>
                              </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td class="contTD" id="container_blocked_modules[0]">
                        <table>
                          <tbody>
                              <tr id="tr_blocked_modules[0]">
                                <th class="th_class1"><span class=""> blocked_modules  </span></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="td_class">   <input type="text" id="blocked_modules[0]" name="blocked_modules[0]" placeholder="" class="" value="03"> </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <th></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <th></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="val_error"></td>
                              </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="contTD"><table>
                      <tbody><tr><th class="th_class1"><span class="">extra column</span></th></tr>
                      <tr><td class="td_class"><input type="text" value="00A"> </td></tr>
                      <tr><th></th></tr>
                      <tr><th></th></tr>
                      <tr><td class="val_error"></td></tr></tbody>
                    </table></td>
                    <td class="contTD" id="container_validation_options[1]">
                        <table>
                          <tbody>
                              <tr id="tr_validation_options[1]">
                                <th class="th_class1"><span class=""> validation_options  </span></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="td_class">   <input type="text" id="validation_options[1]" name="validation_options[1]" placeholder="" class="" value="04"> </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <th></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <th></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="val_error"></td>
                              </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td class="contTD" id="container_validation_display[1]">
                        <table>
                          <tbody>
                              <tr id="tr_validation_display[1]">
                                <th class="th_class1"><span class=""> validation_display  </span></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="td_class">   <input type="text" id="validation_display[1]" name="validation_display[1]" placeholder="" class="" value="05"> </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <th></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <th></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="val_error"></td>
                              </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td class="contTD" id="container_blocked_modules[1]">
                        <table>
                          <tbody>
                              <tr id="tr_blocked_modules[1]">
                                <th class="th_class1"><span class=""> blocked_modules  </span></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="td_class">   <input type="text" id="blocked_modules[1]" name="blocked_modules[1]" placeholder="" class="" value="06"> </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <th></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <th></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="val_error"></td>
                              </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="text-align : left;padding-left:0.5em">
                        <table id="submit_table">
                          <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td><input type="button" class="common_button" id="system_validations_back" name="system_validations_back" value="Back" title="Back">
                                    <input type="reset" class="common_button" id="system_validations_reset" name="system_validations_reset" value="Reset" title="Reset">
                                    <input type="button" class="common_button" id="submit" name="system_validations_submit" value="Submit" title="Submit">
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: you are a genius and a true philanthropist, God bless you, if I ever happen to become very successful in life, I will find you to thank you personally for your philanthropy

Comment: ;-) Thank you for these very kind words! I am pleased that I could help you. Sometimes the tone can get a bit rough here, so it is even nicer to get this positive feedback from you. <3